# Unable to re-change the value of a Javascript attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two images which I'm toggling and a zoom on those images is supposed to be displayed according to the selected image. On the first page load everything works fine (image appears, zoom appears). After I click the image, the image swaps and the zoom works fine as well. However, if I click again, I'm getting the image toggled correctly, but the zoom image does not refresh even for further clicks (keep displaying the zoom for the 2nd loaded image).
I'm trying to change the attributes of data-zoom-image but no luck. Any suggestions?

```
function pageLoad(sender, args) {
    zooming();
}
function chngimg(x) {

       if ($("#zoom_mw").attr("src") == x) {

           var rimage;
           rimage = $("#zoom_mw").attr('rearimage');

           $("#zoom_mw").attr("src", rimage);
           $("#zoom_mw").removeAttr("data-zoom-image");

           $("#zoom_mw").attr("data-zoom-image", rimage);
           $("#zoom_mw").elevateZoom({ scrollZoom: true });
       } else  {
           var fimage;
           fimage = $("#zoom_mw").attr('frontimage');
           $("#zoom_mw").attr("src", fimage);

           $("#zoom_mw").attr("data-zoom-image", fimage);

           $("#zoom_mw").elevateZoom({ scrollZoom: true });
       }
   }

<img style="border:1px solid #e8e8e6;" id="zoom_mw" 
onclick="chngimg('<%= Session("ImagePathFront")%>')"
frontimage='<%= Session("ImagePathFront")%>'
rearimage='<%= Session("ImagePathRear")%>'
    src='<%= Session("ImagePathFront")%>'   
    width="500" height="250"  />
```

Comment: Could you take a look to check if you provided every relevant part of code and libraries you may be using.

Comment: Does the session change dynamically? I assume that it stays the same or do you manipulate the Session content client side from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using **[this library](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom)**. Is this the case?

In [my demo i copied your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/riIAw) and currently

- it toggles the images.
- Your function `pageLoad()` calls a function `zooming()` but the code you provided does not execute pageLoad and the function zooming() is missing.
- The call to `elevateZoom` is not working for me. Are you missing a reference?

If you are using **[elevateZoom](https://github.com/elevateweb/elevatezoom)** than you have to provide the URL for the larger Image

```
<img id="zoom_01" src="small/image1.png" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"/>
```

Their [exsample Gallery & Lightbox](http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples) seems to me that it comes close what you are looking for:

```
<img id="img_01" src="small/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg"/>

<div id="gal1">     
  <a href="#" data-image="small/image1.jpg" data-zoom-image="large/image1.jpg">
    <img id="img_01" src="thumb/image1.jpg" />
  </a>

  <a href="#" data-image="small/image2.jpg" data-zoom-image="large/image2.jpg">
    <img id="img_01" src="thumb/image2.jpg" />
  </a>        
</div>
```

And the matching javascript

```
//initiate the plugin and pass the id of the div containing gallery images
$("#zoom_03").elevateZoom({gallery:'gallery_01', 
        cursor: 'pointer', galleryActiveClass: 'active'
        , imageCrossfade: true
        , loadingIcon: 'http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/spinner.gif'}); 

//pass the images to Fancybox
$("#zoom_03").bind("click", function(e) {  
  var ez =   $('#zoom_03').data('elevateZoom'); 
    $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
  return false;
});
```

Please ask additional questions or comment if i misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, I'm using this library: http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom My version won't work on the page because it loads the image paths from sessions. I'm passing the 'big' image dynamically by adding it as an attribute on each toggle.

Comment: In which target (element) do you want to put the big image? Are the functions `zooming();` and `pageLoad(sender, args)` relevant to your problem? If you have two smaller images A and B (like in my example) each click on the element `<img id="zoom_mw" .../>` should toggle the image (from a to b) and load a matching big image (b_big and a_big) - is this correct? Do the images always match (small_a --> big_a, small_b --> big_b)?

Comment: I fixed it by switching  $("#zoom_mw").attr("data-zoom-image", rimage) statements between the functions.